# Child elements doesn't want to move

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make the image moving, by pressing the up/down/left/right key. I use wpf and canvas for the panel control. Then,
I named the image pacman, and I use onKeyDown when the key isn't pressed, and onKeyUp when the key is pressed, in the xaml code when I try to go to definition it is linked to the right method in the xaml.cs.
Here is the xaml.cs file :

```
    namespace Pacman
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer gameTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Boolean goup, godown, goleft, goright, isGameOver;
        int score, playerSpeed = 8, redGhostSpeed, yellowGhostSpeed, pinkGhostX, pinkGhostY;



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            gameTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
            gameTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

            resetGame();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtScore.Text = "Score : " + score;

            if (goleft && Canvas.GetLeft(pacman) > 0)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(pacman, Canvas.GetLeft(pacman) - playerSpeed);
            }
            if (goright && Canvas.GetLeft(pacman) + (pacman.Width * 2) < Application.Current.MainWindow.Width)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(pacman, Canvas.GetLeft(pacman) + playerSpeed);
            }
            if (goup && Canvas.GetTop(pacman) > 0)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(pacman, Canvas.GetTop(pacman) - playerSpeed);
            }
            if (godown && Canvas.GetTop(pacman) + (pacman.Height * 2) < Application.Current.MainWindow.Height)
            {
                Canvas.SetTop(pacman, Canvas.GetTop(pacman) + playerSpeed);
            }
        }

        private void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                goup = true;
            }
            if(e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                godown = true;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                goleft = true;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                goright = true;
            }
        }

        private void onKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                goup = false;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                godown = false;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                goleft = false;
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                goright = false;
            }
        }

        private void resetGame()
        {
            txtScore.Text = "Score : 0";
            score = 0;

            redGhostSpeed = 5;
            yellowGhostSpeed = 5;
            pinkGhostX = 5;
            pinkGhostY = 5;
            playerSpeed = 8;

            isGameOver = false;

            gameTimer.Start();
        }

        private void gameOver(string message)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I think the code should be working by now, but it didn't
Anyone knows what should I do?

edit :
here is the xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="Pacman.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pacman"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Pacman Game" Height="700" Width="600" Background="Black"
        xmlns:gif ="https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif">
    <Canvas Background="Black" KeyDown="onKeyDown" KeyUp="onKeyUp" Focusable="True">
<Image x:Name="pacman" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="Resources\right.gif"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Thank You so much

Comment: Do you ever initialize the Left and Top properties anywhere? Their default value is `double.NaN`.

Comment: debug it and inspect the controls' coordinate runtime values to see what's going on.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend to only use a single field (e.g. an enum) for the moving direction - instead of four separate booleans.

Comment: @Clemens  i didn't

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface i don't understand how to debug, i'm sorry

Comment: That's an indispensable skill. please at least make sure that the timer event handler and the keyboard event handlers are ever called - if not by debugging, then set any other property of any other control, for example a text, to prove at runtime. does the score appear? (this is not to say you should not have posted this question; but if you expect anybody to tell you where the problem is, we ask for a minimal, complete example).

Comment: it may be as simple as `onKeyDown` not wired up - show xaml as well.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface yeah, the score does appear, I already add the xaml code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix this guys, I forgot to give the canvas name and `MyCanvas.Focus();` on my Timer_Tick()